# jsTree drag and drop on multiple trees

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jstree

I need to have *n* number of jsTress on which the user can drop items from one common tree. Initially these trees can be empty, so when the user drops an item on one of the trees I need to send an AJAX request to the server to save this on the database.

In order to achieve n trees I have one loop which creates the `<div>` to hold them, something like this:

```
var DayToday = moment();
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  dayHTML += '<div class="col-md-2 column sortable"> \
                <div class="portlet portlet-sortable green-turquoise box" id="day_' + i + '_portlet"> \
                  <div class="portlet-title"> \
                    <div class="caption">' + DayToday.format('MMMM Do YYYY') + '</div> \
                    <div class="tools"> \
                      <a href="javascript:;" class="collapse"> </a> \
                      <a href="javascript:;" class="reload"> </a> \
                      <a href="javascript:;" class="remove"> </a> \
                    </div> \
                    </div> \
                    <div class="portlet-body"> \
                      <div id="day_' + i + '_tree" class="tree-demo" style="min-height:50px;"> \
                      <li></li> \
                    </div> \
                  </div> \
                </div> \
                <div class="portlet portlet-sortable-empty"> </div> \
            </div>';
  DayToday = DayToday.add(1, 'days');
}

$("#sortable_portlets").append(dayHTML);
```

Then a loop to add a JS tree:

```
DayToday = moment();
var currTree = [];
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  currTree[i] = $(dayTrees[i]).jstree({
      "core": {
        "id": DayToday.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        "animation": 150,
        'check_callback': function(operation, node, node_parent, node_position, more) {
          console.log(node_parent);
          return true; //allow all other operations
        },
        "themes": {
          "stripes": false
        },
        "data": {
          "url": "http://localhost:8888/bizsked/public/taskassignment/json?asg_date=" + DayToday.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
          "dataType": "json"
        }
      },
      "rules": {
        droppable: ["tree-drop"],
        multiple: true,
        deletable: "all",
        draggable: "all"
      },
      "dnd": {
        open_timeout: 100
      },
      "plugins": ["dnd"]

    })
    .on("move_node.jstree", function(e, data) {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .on("copy_node.jstree", function(e, data) {
      console.log(data);
    });
  DayToday = DayToday.add(1, 'days');
}
```

SO in effect, you can drag and drop from each tree to the other. But what i cannot seem to understand is how I can get the ID or some id of the tree which has been dropped on. Ok, so I can easily find out the item which is being dragged, and if its is dropped onto a child (not the main node) then I can find that ID, but if it is dropped onto an empty tree or the main node (#), I cannot find the ID, only '#'. Maybe I am missing something fundamental but all I need to know is (a) the id of the item being dropped (easy) and (b) the ID of the tree on which it has been dropped.. (not so easy).

Any suggestions on how i can do this would be much appreciated as I have been trying to figure this out for two days now!

Comment: Try to explore the `data` object in your `move_node` event. You should have an `instance` property somewhere there. That is the tree.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't spot it before now, but you are right - heres what I needed -  console.log(data.instance.element.context.id);  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to explore the `data` object in your `move_node` event. You should have an `instance` property somewhere there. That is the tree.